# App for File store and viewer

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, ios-appstore, uti

I am looking at an ipad app which can be used to store files locally as well as supports multiple types for viewing. E.g. Doc, xls, ppt, etc

I heard Goodreader is one such app, but was looking for something free..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about Documents 2 Free. I use it and I like it.

http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/documents-2-free-spreadsheet/id314894105?mt=8

Although it's not an ipad only app.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox can store files locally and also sync files with other device, and it support a lot of file formats i.e. doc, xls, ppt. And it's free